# Lighttpd + fastcgi + python (for django) slow on first request

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm having a problem with a django website I host with lighttpd + fastcgi.
It works great but it seems that the first request always takes up to 3seconds. Subsequent requests are much faster (<1s).

I activated access logs in lighttpd in order to track the issue. But I'm kind of stuck.

Here are logs where I 'lose' 4s (from 10:04:17 to 10:04:21):

```
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (mod_fastcgi.c.3636) handling it in mod_fastcgi 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.473) Path         :  
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 10:04:17: (response.c.544) Path         : /var/www/finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 10:04:21: (response.c.128) Response-Header: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 09:04:21 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 09:14:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 09:04:21 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

I guess that if there is a problem, it's whith my configuration. So here is the way I launch my django app:

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=3033
```

And here is my lighttpd conf:

```
    server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_fastcgi",
        "mod_accesslog",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
accesslog.filename           = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log" 

debug.log-request-header = "enable"
debug.log-response-header = "enable"
debug.log-file-not-found = "enable"
debug.log-request-handling = "enable"
debug.log-timeouts = "enable"
debug.log-ssl-noise = "enable"
debug.log-condition-cache-handling = "enable"
debug.log-condition-handling = "enable"



fastcgi.server = (
    "/finderauto.fcgi" => (
        "main" => (
            # Use host / port instead of socket for TCP fastcgi
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 3033,
            #"socket" => "/home/finderadmin/finderauto.sock",
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
        )
    ),
)
alias.url = (
    "/media" => "/home/user/django/contrib/admin/media/",
)

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
    "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/finderauto.fcgi$1",
)

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                                "index.htm", "default.htm",
                               " index.lighttpd.html" )

url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl"

dir-listing.encoding        = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing          = "enable"

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/x-javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

If any of you could help me finding out where I lose these 3 or 4 s. I would much appreciate.

UPDATE: One more info. I activated fastcgi logs and I got the 3s delay between the following two fcgi logs:

```
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (mod_fastcgi.c.3636) handling it in mod_fastcgi 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.473) Path         :  
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (response.c.544) Path         : /var/www/finderauto.fcgi 
2012-12-01 18:18:12: (mod_fastcgi.c.3061) got proc: pid: 0 socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:3033 load: 1
```

Maybe it's linked to a fastcgi configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. There's only one log here, not two. 2. I have the same problem with lighttpd and PHP, on windows. Do you have a solution ? Post it as answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you do not have much activity on your site? I'm thinking that the python interpreter is removed from memory before the next request. Do you have plenty of RAM to hold all your software in memory? Are there other tasks running which could push python out of memory - maybe just maintenance, or a mail server?